# Entity Framework INNER JOIN with "BETWEEN" date range

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there a way with entity framework to do a "INNER JOIN" with a "BETWEEN"?

I have a table with a list of date of the first day of each month, and I want to associate all my record that are in the month so I can group by month after.

Anyway what I want to reproduce is something like that:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Assignments as a
INNER JOIN monthList as m ON ( m.Date BETWEEN a.StartDate AND a.EndDate)
```

Here is what I tried but doesn't work...

```
var query = (from a in Context.Assignments
             join m in monthList on (m >= a.StartDate && m <= a.EndDate);
```

One other thing to note is that `montList` is not part of my context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this answer: [LINQ Join On Between Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535132/linq-join-on-between-clause)

In a LINQ to Entities query two `from` in a row also produce `INNER JOIN` in SQL statement.

In your case you would have the following.

```
var query = from a in Context.Assignments
            from m in monthList
            where m >= a.StartDate && m <= a.EndDate
            select new { a.SomeProperty, a.AnotherProperty };
```

In your case, since `monthList` is not part of your `DbContext` object, `Context.Assignments` will be queried first to pull it into local memory and then this result will be *inner joined* with `monthList` to produce `query` object.

Comment: Updated with `select new { }` for query completeness.